# Tap fingerprint, not swipe

Tags: fingerprint-reader

Is there option to use tap fingerprint? I really don't want swipe fingerprint scanner. My laptop has quick scanner (mi notebook pro), on windows it works immediately and pretty good, like on smartphones, but on ubuntu almost always enter password is easier then use fingerprint (I have long password by the way).

p.s. are there swipe fingerprint scanners still in 2019? I've never seen those at all.

---

- My laptop: Xiaomi Mi Notebook Pro 15.6 Intel Core i7 16/512Gb/MX250 2019 Dark Grey (JYU4147CN)
- Ubuntu version: 19.10
- lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f3:0c1a Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2cb7 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. XiaoMi USB 2.0 Webcam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

- lspci -v

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
    Subsystem: Xiaomi Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=10 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Xiaomi UHD Graphics 620
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 138
    Memory at b2000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
    Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
    Subsystem: Xiaomi Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
    Memory at b4228000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [dc] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [f0] PCI Advanced Features

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Xiaomi Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 125
    Memory at b4210000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Xiaomi Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Memory at b4229000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal

00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Xiaomi Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at b422a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Xiaomi Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at b422b000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Xiaomi Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 137
    Memory at b422c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: b3000000-b3ffffff [size=16M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000a0000000-00000000b1ffffff [size=288M]
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Xiaomi Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [220] Secondary PCI Express <?>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #8 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: None
    Memory behind bridge: b4100000-b41fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: None
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Xiaomi Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [220] Secondary PCI Express <?>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: None
    Memory behind bridge: b4000000-b40fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: None
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Xiaomi Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [220] Secondary PCI Express <?>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point LPC Controller/eSPI Controller (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Xiaomi Sunrise Point LPC Controller/eSPI Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Xiaomi Sunrise Point-LP PMC
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at b4224000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Xiaomi Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 139
    Memory at b4220000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at b4200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Xiaomi Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at b422d000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 4040 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108BM [GeForce MX250] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Xiaomi GP108BM [GeForce MX250]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
    Memory at b3000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [disabled] [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at <ignored> [disabled]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [250] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [258] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [420] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
    Capabilities: [900] Secondary PCI Express <?>
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia

02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 136
    Memory at b4100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [40] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number d0-ab-d5-ff-ff-b8-09-f7
    Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [154] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983 (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16, NUMA node 0
    Memory at b4000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/32 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=33 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [148] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
    Capabilities: [158] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [168] Secondary PCI Express <?>
    Capabilities: [188] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [190] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme
```

Comment: 1) Without providing three things: a) your Ubuntu version number, b) your make and model of laptop (model number must be obtained from the serial number sticker), and  c) the result of `lspci -v` , answering this is well-night impossible. Please click [edit] to provide this information into the question; please do not use Add Comment, instead use [edit]. 2) That's a question best asked in http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com as it's off-topic here.